# Form and Entity class usages

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

What is the best practice for using `Form` and `Entity` classes? Should I use the same class as `Form` and `Entity` or should I use different `Pojos` for this purpose? There are pros and cons for each situation:

1. `Form` and `Entity` in one class: You decrease number of `Pojos` in your project (maybe some Form classes will be the exact duplicate of Entity class). But Entity classes look ugly with `Persistence` and `Validation` annotations combined together in one class, also validation goes in upper level (web) and persistence is a lower level (dao) operation, it seems not so good to use the same class as Form and Entity.
2. `Form` and `Entity` as different `Pojos`: Your classes look good, `Form` pojos have only `Validation` annotations and `Entity` pojos have only `Persistence` annotations, so you can easily focus on each part of project. But you increase the number of classes in your project, an additional package for form/entity classes. And a converter method/class should be added for `Form -> Entity` transformation.

I know that this question is something 'up to you', but I want to know the best practice with explanation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First, I need to explain that in almost all situations, the model can solve the problem, and there is no need to have another class for the UI, and you just have to send the model to the Client in the controller. But in some complicated circumstances, you may not need to do this. For example, consider that the relationships between the models are very complex and related to each other to understand the subject of the relationships below.

```
public class Department {
    String departmentName;
    List <Employee> employeeList;
}

public class Employee {
    String firstName;
    String lastName
    Department department;
    List <Job> jobList;
}

public class Job {
    Integer id;
    String jobTitle;
    Employee employee;
    User createdBy;
    User updatedBy;
}

public class User {
    String username;
    List <Department> departmentList;
}
```

In this case, the model request displayed in the UI layer is something different than the first one. This situation seems to me to be two reasons.

1) The state in which the model needs an attribute that essentially acquires an aggregate of things. For example, the representation of each department and the number of employees in this case. Using the DTO approach, a new class should be created.

```
public class DepartmentDTO {
    String departmentName;
    Long employeeCount;
}
```

2) The situation where the information displayed is a different part of the information. For example, consider the need for the above information to only show the information related to Job as shown below

```
 public class JobViewModel {
    Integer id;
    String jobTitle;
    String employeeFirstName;
    string employeeLastName;
}


public class JobViewModel2 {
    Integer id;
    String jobTitle;
    String employeeFirstName;
    String employeeLastName;
    String employeeDepartmentName;
    String createdByUsername;
    String updaedByUsername;
}
```

As you can see, you need to have a different view of the original model in this case. How does this transformation work? Here you need to have a mapstruct and dozer framework. These frameworks have the task of turning this model into ViewModel.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ali. My question was exactly about Forms (not model) and Entity classes. I use Spring framework (Spring Forms + Spring Data JPA). And I want to know is it a good practice to use the same class as a Form and JPA Entity? Because some fields (password confirmation) should not map to a database column, we should mark it as @ Transient, and also a lot of validation annotations should be added to JPA Entity class fields (@ NotEmpty, @ NotNull etc). And I wanna know should I use all these annotations in one class or should I use different classes. Is there any best practice?

Comment: i think yes all annotation in One class